# "bubble clusters" project (draggability, grouping, drawing, merging groups)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, swing, awt

I am interested in creating a bubble-clusters-like project in Java (see http://www-ui.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~takeo/research/bubble/index.html for a working example).

My goal is to allow the user create a bunch of post-it notes that can be grouped and moved around like the example. (There will be other features, but I am having the most difficulty starting this feature). I will be using Java and Swing.

Here are some things I am reading up on:

-draggability (first priority, using JTextAreas?)

-grouping

-merging

-drawing (wont worry too much about that now)

I am not too experienced with creating Java GUI and swing, so I don't know how difficult it would be. Any thoughts or readings/tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the implementation of Bubble Sets by Christopher Collins (http://faculty.uoit.ca/collins/research/bubblesets/index.html).  His source code is free and easy to use.

Also, the Prefuse visual toolkit ([prefuse.org](http://prefuse.org)) would be a great way to (i) get a project running quickly and (ii) see how a good visual toolkit is written.  Draggability, rendering, layouts, interaction, and many other features are given in this toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

This might be relevant to your interests: http://www.oldamascus.com/~lio/vis/graphlix/. Note the clustering :) It's Processing, but the code can be easily ported over to Swing (Processing is basically just a programming 'environment' where loads of useful functions are dumped into one file).